# Can't import matplotlib due to type conflict

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to import matplotlib while running python 3 from my command line (macOS Montery 12.6) I get:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 18:29:29) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

>>> import matplotlib
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 876, in <module>
        rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 778, in _rc_params_in_file
        with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 751, in _open_file_or_url
        fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 231, in expanduser
        path = os.fspath(path)
    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PosixPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing conda and pip installations

- `pip uninstall matplotlib`
- `pip uninstall pillow`
- `conda uninstall matplotlib`
- `conda install matplotlib`

may save your current enviroment other wise

- `conda create -n new_env python matplotlib`

I hope this will help you

Comment: Didn't work; With your first four lines I got

Comment: Didn't work; With your first four lines I got a dump of environment variables, followed by
 
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.\n\nUpload successful. Your "conda create" command also produced errors too long to include.

Where do I go now?